# Attempting to use airmon-ng returns error

Tags: permissions, mac-address, airmon-ng

So im trying to use airmon-ng so i can get some mac addresses and deauth them 'with permission, ofc' im on Nethunter and airmon returns this

```
ls: cannot access '/sys/class/net': No such file or directory
PHY     Interface       Driver          Chipset

null    p2p0            ??????          non-mac80211 device? (report this!)
null    wlan0           ??????          non-mac80211 device? (report this!)

root@localhost:~#
```

Answer (score 0):

What's the output of `ls /sys/class/net`?

```bsh
$ ls -l /sys/class/net/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan 30 18:23 enp7s0f1 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.5/0000:07:00.1/net/enp7s0f1/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan 30 18:23 lo -> ../../devices/virtual/net/lo/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan 30 18:23 wlp0s20f3 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.3/net/wlp0s20f3/
```

You should get a list of of you network interfaces. If not, then your system is messed up.

Comment: Tried the command, returned ls: /sys/class/net no such file or directory